# Reading Version from manifest.json in a Chrome Packaged App

Tags: google-chrome-extension, dart, angular-dart, google-chrome-app

I want to display my apps version number dynamically on a page, so was wondering if there is a way to read it from the manifest.json in a Chrome Packaged App written in DART language ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```dart
import 'package:chrome/chrome_app.dart' as chrome;

void main() {
  print(chrome.runtime.getManifest()['version']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't provide a DART-specific answer, but appropriate Chrome API is [`chrome.runtime.getManifest()`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-getManifest).

It returns <del>a string</del> an object representing your manifest file; extract the version number with `.version`.

Comment: If that helps and you do implement it in DART, please leave a better-fitting answer.

Comment: Thanks, Robert has given the details out, but the key was to use the getManifast() function in the chrome API.